# prevent combining characters if single characters are available

Tags: symbols, fontspec, unicode, characters

I am working a lot with characters such as:

> ā ū ī š ṣ ḫ ḥ ǧ ġ ṯ ṭ ẓ ḍ ḏ.

There are (at least) two ways to typeset such characters

1. either as a single character or
2. as a combined character.

Take `ā` as an example. Either (#1) `ā` is set as the unicode character `U+0101 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH MACRON)` or (#2) it is set as a combination of `U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A)` and `U+0304 (COMBINING MACRON)`

How can I force LuaLaTeX to use method #1 instead of method #2? Method #2 seems to be the default even though my source text contains the single character "ā" (`U+0101`)? My font does contain "ā" as a single character (`U+0101`) just as it contains all other characters I need as single characters. I don't want LaTeX to create these characters through combination.

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
ā a
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you know they are typeset as a combination? It seems to me that does what you want compiling your code.

Comment: @karlkoeller : I copy from the pdf and paste into a text editor. When I then analyse what I got in the text editor I am told that it is the combined versions. I assumed that this means that the pdf itself consists of combined characters, because I further assumed that merely copying and pasting does not import any transformation from single to combined characters that would entail a difference between what I saw and what I got. Am I mistaken in assuming that?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me. Copying and pasting gives me the right Unicode values for the single characters.

Comment: @karlkoeller : hmmm. Apple Preview, the TeXShop preview window, and the BibDesk tex-preview window give me the combined versions upon copy+paste. Adobe Acrobat Pro gives me the single ones. How is that? It seems that you may be right. LaTeX typesets the single ones but most pdf-apps do not copy and paste the single ones. That strikes me as strange.

Comment: Whether I open the output pdf file with Acrobat Pro or with Apple Preview, I get the exact same look of the characters. (I use MacTeX2014 on a system that runs MacOSX 10.10.1.) What steps do you take to analyze the output?

Comment: I use TeXShop's built-in `Character Info` which analyses the selected character(s) and tells me which one and how many. Secondly, in Word when using backspace after an `ā`, the macron is deleted first and only after a second hit the `a` itself. If it is a single character, the whole thing is deleted at once. By the way: I use the same system and the same OS version. Something else: I also experienced differences of copy+paste results between Acrobat and Preview with regard to the whitespace between words. Acrobat is more reliable while Preview sometimes does not copy them. Outputisthenlikethis

Comment: This is not a luatex problem. Mac OS uses the "decomposed" form of umlauts in the file system and some/many/all (I have windows and so don't know the extend of the problem) copy&pasting actively replace composed chars by the decomposed form. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1235/_index.html. If your input contains decomposed chars you could (with a feature file) force luatex to create a pdf with composed chars but copy & pasting from this pdf could change the chars again.

Comment: I agree that this is somehow off-topic (because the issue is not with TeX), but a nice answer (by @Ulrike?) explaining the problem would carry a lot of value I think. It would be sufficient to just repost the comment as an answer ;)

Comment: If I copy the output and paste it in http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ I get, in the “Hex code input” box, `0101`; if I paste it in other applications I get `0061 0304`. So it depends on the application where you paste. Note: using Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Let me rephrase the question and then you can post your comment as an answer, alright?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was resolved in the comments and is somehow off-topic anyway.